# expressionengine related entries dropdown value

Tags: expressionengine, channel

I have 2 channels. Channel 2 has a dropdown select box relating to channel 1. I want to display all info regarding both channels on a single page:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel1|channel2" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}
{title}
Channel1 info: {tag_from_channel1}
...                             
{reverse_related_entries id="channel2"}
...
{/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I'm getting ID from {tag_from_channel1} instead of value. How can I display value instead of ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `require_entry="yes"` parameter, which aide in your troubleshooting:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel1|channel2" limit="1"}
    {title}

    {reverse_related_entries}
        {title}
    {/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You can further debug your issue by eliminating the URL causing a problem by hard-coding your Channel Entries query with `dynamic="off"` and specifying a single entry with `entry_id="99"`:

```
{exp:channel:entries ... dynamic="off" entry_id="99"}
```

Also, the `{reverse_related_entries}` tag shouldn't have an `id=` parameter. From the [ExpressionEngine Relationship Documentation](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/relationships.html):

> Unlike the Related Entries tag, the *Reverse Related Entries* tag does
>   not contain an ID parameter as there is no need.

Did you perhaps intend to use `{related entries}` instead?